# Liquibase to create table with Postgis "Geometry" type

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, postgis, liquibase

I'm composing a liquibase script to create a table with `Geometry` column (from PostGis extenstion of PostGreSQL DB)

However, I couldn't manage to get it working. My script:

```
  - changeSet:
      id: 5-change-set-places
      comment: Create places table
      author: LongLe
      validCheckSum: 1:any
      changes:
        - sql:
            dbms: postgresql
            endDelimiter: ;
            splitStatements: true
            sql: |
              CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "${schema}"."places" (
                "id" bigint NOT NULL,
                "geom" GEOMETRY(Geometry, 4326) NOT NULL
              );
              GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON "${schema}"."places" TO "${rolename}";
              ALTER TABLE "${schema}"."places"
                DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "places_pkey",
                ADD CONSTRAINT "places_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");
```

However, it failed with below error:

```
ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist
```

I also referred to liquibase-spatial extension https://github.com/lonnyj/liquibase-spatial and compose the equivalent config:

```
  - changeSet:
      id: 5-change-set-places
      comment: Create places table
      author: LongLe
      validCheckSum: 1:any
      changes:
        - createTable:
            columns:
              - column:
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                    primaryKey: true
                    primaryKeyName: places_pkey
                  name: id
                  type: bigint
              - column:
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  name: geom
                  type: GEOMETRY(Geometry,4326)
            tableName: test
```

But it still failed with the error:

> 31-03-2021 21:07:31.587 [main] WARN
> c.m.ms.block...applyLiquibase -
> Error applying liquibase attempt 5 : Migration failed for change set
> classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::5-change-set-places::LongLe:
> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist   Position: 67 [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE
> testschema.places (id BIGINT NOT NULL, geom
> geometry(Geometry, 4326) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT places_pkey
> PRIMARY KEY (id))]

But when I took out the *SQL from the log* to run:

```
CREATE TABLE testschema.places (id BIGINT NOT NULL, geom geometry(Geometry, 4326) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT places_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

**Then it works just fine.**

I must have missed some very simple thing, but I checked up & down without any clue. Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: Not sure but just a thought. Have you tried "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;" before using "geometry" from the extension?

Comment: Hi @RakhiAgrawal, yes, I do install PostGis before. Having added that in the previous script still produces the same issue

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe Thanks! This turn out to be the issue. I added one SQL command to include "public" into the search path and it works

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have run

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Then schema qualify the data type. If the extension was created in `public`, use

```
CREATE TABLE places (geom public.geometry, ...);
```